# Ковариантность и контрвариантность обобщений

Tags: c#, ооп

Как правильно и для чего используются ковариантность и контрвариантность обобщённых интерфейсов и делегатов. Может есть какие видео или статьи доходчивые, чтобы разобраться с этим раз и навсегда?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance

Comment: Уже написал ответ, а тут вопрос закрыли(

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk: Тогда напишите напишите этот же ответ к тому вопросу?